# Colliding issues with .htaccess rewrite URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Alright so heres my .htaccess that is located in `http://example.com/forums/`

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^threads/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ forums-threads.php?code=$1&pn=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^threads/([^/]+)$ forums-threads.php?code=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^new-thread/([^/]+)$ forums-new-thread.php?code=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^new-post/([^/]+)$ forums-new-post.php?code=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?code=$1&pn=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?code=$1 [QSA]
```

Now the problem is, when I go to a new thread URL [like this example](http://example.com/forums/new-thread/eUjJP-Announcements) it instead goes to the index page and the `$_GET` variables that are outputted are

```
Array ( [code] => eUjJP-Announcements [pn] => eUjJP-Announcements )
```

I'm wondering how I can resolve this issue, and if there are any other issues in the `.htaccess` code above that need to be corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because subsequent rule below is still executing since you don't have any other condition to block it.

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forums/

RewriteRule \.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^threads/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ forums-threads.php?code=$1&pn=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^threads/([^/]+)$ forums-threads.php?code=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^new-thread/([^/]+)$ forums-new-thread.php?code=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^new-post/([^/]+)$ forums-new-post.php?code=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?code=$1&pn=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?code=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I had to remove `RewriteBase /` since its in the /forums/ directory. not the root.
I replaced the code you gave me with what I had
Now whenever I go to http://example.com/forums/ it just keeps redirecting to the same page and the $_GET variables that output are

`Array ( [code] => index.php )`

Comment: You didn't provide this detail (/forums) in your question. I have made an edit, try it now.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize I forgot that. My apologies. 
I replaced the code again, and now when I go to http://example.com/forums it keeps refreshing/redirecting to the index.php page located in the /forums/ and the $_GET variables are saying `Array ( [code] => [L] )`

Comment: If you goto `example.com/index.php?code=forums` does it load forum properly?

Comment: Yes, Sorry I forgot to add something in the index which was causing that. There is a new issue that has arose tho. Whenever I vist
http://example.com/forums/new-thread/eUjJP-Announcements
It just goes to the index.php with the $_GET variables being `Array ( [code] => eUjJP-Announcements )`

Comment: Thank you so much, It is fixed now. Ive been at this error since 11:30 AM XD, Your a live savor.